# Derivative of limited convolution

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals, convolution

If I take infinite convolution, I know that its derivative is the convolution between one term and other term's derivative.

However, I am interested on derivative of

$$\dfrac {d}{dt}\int_0^t f (t) g (t-a) da$$

i.e. in terms of **limited convolution**.

Many thanks in advance!

======

***EDIT: Please review comments on answer***

Comment: Just a terminology note: "*limited convolution*" is also customarily called "*Volterra convolution*".

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @tossimmar 's answer gives some preliminary remarks, but I think this answer will provide the asker with more of what he/she is looking for. First of all, Leibniz's integral rule, in most general form, is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t,s)\mathrm{d}s\right)=f\left(t,b(t)\right)b'(t)-f\left(t,a(t)\right)a'(t)+\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,s)\mathrm{d}s$$
In our case, this gives us
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(t)g(t-s)\mathrm{d}s\right)=f(t)g(0)+\int_0^tf'(t)g(t-s)\mathrm{d}s+\int_0^tf(t)g'(t-s)\mathrm{d}s$$
Of course, we could write this in terms of this partial convolution which I'll denote with an tilded asterisk:
$$\mathrm{D}(f~\tilde{*}~g)=g(0)\cdot f+f'~\tilde{*}~g+f~\tilde{*}~g'$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Apply the special case of Liebniz's Rule, $$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{a}^{x}h(x,t)dt\bigg) = h(x,x) + \int_{a}^{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(x,t)dt.$$

Comment: Hello, many thanks. I'm researching a little bit more, should not you use Leibniz Rule?

Comment: @Na'omi Yes, we can apply Leibniz's Rule. I will edit my answer to include it.

Comment: Thank you! So, I can write using definite convolution that $d/dt (f\star g)=f(t)g(0)+f\star g'+f'\star g$, what do you think?